# dojo's event.preventDefault() not working on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

i'm quite new to Dojo, but i am trying to convert an existing javascript interface from pure javascript to Dojo.

i am stucked on the following problem

basically i tryied to convert

```
<a id="myLink" onclick="myfunction()">bla</a>

function myfunction() {
//some funny code
return false; //To PREVENT default link behaviour
}
```

to the following

```
var handle = dojo.connect(dojo.byId('myLink'),'onclick',function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //took from dojo reference
        //same code that worked in pure js

});
```

I cannot figure the problem out. Both Chrome and Firefox don't fire any error or exception, so i guess, there are no syntax errors.

I tryed to connect that function to a input submit instead of the link and **it worked** but i need it to be connected to a link....

Maybe i'm just tired, but i swear i can't see the error...

Comment: Can't you just use `return false;`?

Comment: Did you remove the onclick attribute from the original link? Also, make sure that you wrap the link handler within dojo.ready() or that the link handler appears after the element in the HTML.

Comment: @PeeHaa if you mean to add return false; at the bottom of the callback, i tried and it does not work. I want to figure out why the code above does not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your HTML body:

```
<a id="myLink">bla</a>
```

On your HTML header :

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    dojo.ready(function(){
        dojo.connect(dojo.byId("myLink"), "onclick", null, function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            console.debug("Default behaviour prevented");
        });
    });
</script>
```

More on that here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html

Comment: I don't think you need that "null" on the dojo.connect arguments.

Comment: You are right... http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/connect.html#dojo-connect

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and thought I'm going insane. But then I found this dojo method:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

over here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html and that finally stopped the hyperlink from doing its thing. Apparently dojo provides its own event object which doesn't behave like the native one.